# How to check if a core update, like 4.9.8 → 5.0, involves a database update (migration)?

Tags: database, upgrade

And where do I (reliably) look for this kind of information? I find myself googling for 'wordpress changelog' on every other update...

Background: usually I use a "skeletal" WP installation (seperate `wp`/`app` and `wp-content` folders), so I could try out the new major version and check for theme incompatibilites by "hotswapping" the `wp` folder. And I'm worried that "swapping back" might not work due to a migrated DB. Yes I know, I should always back it up before an update anyway. Question still stands :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after some thinking I came up with this:

[Codex / Wordpress Versions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Current_events) has Changelogs, but these seem to mention (recent) database upgrades implicitly, starting at 5.0. (Compare how [Matomo explicitly states DB upgrades](https://matomo.org/changelog/piwik-3-0-0/)). Maybe this will be enough for future versions, here's the thorough, cumbersome way that works for older versions, too:

1. check `db_version` at [Codex / Wordpress Versions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Current_events), **or** manually/programmatically:

   1. check `wp-includes/version.php` of the version we are updating *from*, [4.9.8](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/4.9.8/wp-includes/version.php#L14):
      `$wp_db_version = 38590;`
   2. repeat for version we are updating *to*; [5.0](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5.0/wp-includes/version.php#L14): `$wp_db_version = 43764;`
2. check `upgrade_all` in `wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php`, for [4.9.8→5.0 / 38590→43764](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5.0/wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php#L642-L643):

   ```php
   // ...
   if ( $wp_current_db_version < 37965 ) // false
       upgrade_460();

   if ( $wp_current_db_version < 43764 ) // true!
       upgrade_500();
   ```
3. finally, inspecting [`upgrade_500`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5.0/wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php#L1820-L1836), reveals some Gutenberg-juggling and a `FIXME` :)
4. Conclusion: Only very minor database upgrades (one site option is set), so it should be fine, just keep an eye out for Gutenberg & Classic Editor plugin.

UPDATE/EDIT, regarding the "Background": So I did do a manual update 4.9.9→5.0 and then a manual downgrade 5.0→4.9.9 (4.9.8 and .9 don't differ DB-wise). I was presented with the "DB Upgrade required" screen **both** ways, and proceeded. What happens upon downgrade would need more research; my guess is that you only see the screen and none of the `upgrade_*` functions are executed. After up-and-downgrade everything *looks* normal, at least for this minimal, fresh install. So I will feel free to upgrade 4.9.8 to 5.0, knowing I can switch back should anything go wrong. YMMV, of course, especially when other plugins and themes are involved. Wouldn't do it for bigger version jumps, though :)

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded 2 of my sites from version 4.9.8 to 5.0 and it did not require any database update. Also I had installed Gutenberg and the update disables the plugin since it's already integrated with the new version.

If you are concerned about the update, backup your database and site before the upgrading.

Comment: Thanks for the practical input! For reference documentation see my answer which also shows that there technically can be DB changes, if very minor/negligible.

Comment: I just upgraded a site from 4.9.9 to 5.0 manually and I did see the "DB Upgrade required" screen. Is it possible that the Dashboard update process doesn't mention it or it scrolls by quickly?